# Use of ESPAsyncWebServer.h with ArduinoJson version 6 for Master-Client transactions

Tags: esp32, web-server, http, json

I want to communicate two (2) ESP32's via Json commands using ESPAsyncWeb.h. The master should have specific operations to execute and respond to the client, and the client should be able to send specific Json commands to ask questions and receive responses. I have tried the method below but is throwing me weird errors such as

> cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'ArduinoJson::JsonObject&' {aka 'ArduinoJson6185_91::OBjectRef&'} to an rvalue of type 'ArduinoJson6185_91::enable_if<true, ArduinJson6185_91::ObjectRef>::type' {aka 'ArduinoJson6185_91::ObjectRef'}

I am not sure how to implement the operations for sending Json and receiving response from the Server using ArduinoJson 6. If anyone could enligthen me on how to conduct such transactions I'd appreciate it.

```
 void setup(){

//start serial comm
//Broadcast as WiFi SoftAP

 server.on("/command", HTTP_POST, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request, JsonVariant &json) 
          {JsonObject& jsonObj = json.as<JsonObject>();
           uint8_t command = jsonObj["C"];
           String response;
           switch(command){
                           case 0: response = "{\"SCAN\":\"received_scan\"}";
                           request -> send(200, "application/json", response);
                           return;
                           case 1: /*...similar stuff */

                           case 2: /*...*/
}});
server.begin();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried following the examples in the [ESPAsyncWebServer](https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer#json-body-handling-with-arduinojson) documentation? The code you used is different from the example.

Answer (score 1):

> cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'ArduinoJson::JsonObject&' {aka 'ArduinoJson6185_91::ObjectRef&'} to an rvalue of type 'ArduinoJson6185_91::enable_if<true, ArduinJson6185_91::ObjectRef>::type' {aka 'ArduinoJson6185_91::ObjectRef'}

In other words, "cannot assign `JsonObject` to `JsonObject&`".
The compiler refuses to save a reference to a temporary variable because the reference would inevitably dangle.

To fix this issue, you must remove the ampersand (`&`) after `JsonObject`, like so:

```cpp
JsonObject jsonObj = json.as<JsonObject>();
```

And it would be best if you also did the same for `JsonVariant`.

BTW, the cast from [`JsonVariant`](https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/jsonvariant/) to [`JsonObject`](https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/jsonobject/) isn't necessary in your case, so you could simplify your program to:

```cpp
server.on("/command", HTTP_POST,
          [](AsyncWebServerRequest* request, JsonVariant json) {
            switch (json["C"].as<uint8_t>()) {
              case 0:
                request->send(200, "application/json",
                              "{\"SCAN\":\"received_scan\"}");
                return;
                
              case 1: /*...similar stuff */

              case 2: /*...*/
            }
          });
```

I recommend that you have a look at [ArduinoJson's documentation](https://arduinojson.org/v6/doc/); I heard it's pretty good ;-)